# Menus not visible in some apps in Xubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, xubuntu

I've been using Ubuntu 12.04 for a few weeks and recently added the xubuntu desktop as well.  I have noticed that in some applications, there is no menu present.  For example, in Thunar, their is no menu (File, View, etc.), so I can't figure out how to "show hidden files."  Could this be some conflict between xubuntu and unity's global menu.  I want to be able to log in under either on my netbook, so uninstalling one or the other is not an option.  Any ideas?

Comment: On Xubuntu 12.04, Ctrl + h toggles "show hidden files".

Comment: I also sometimes don't see menus but that's only the case when my xfwm4 crashed and so `xfwm4 --replace` restarts the window manager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I solved this particular problem.  I was having problem with a lack of menus in gnome-shell as well.  I went into dconf editor, clicked on 'org' then on 'global menu.'  I then unchecked the 'enable global menu' box.  Since then, I have been able to see menus in both xubuntu and gnome-shell.  I haven't noticed any loss in functionality in global menu when I'm logged into Unity.  Thanks everyone for the answers.

Comment: well done for solving this - please click the tick button next to your answer to mark as accepted - and thus close the question.